# Make baseline on Clearcase based on View, not Stream?

Tags: version-control, clearcase

Why does the "make baseline" command on clearcase explorer need the concerned user's view ? (indeed, it asks for the "view context")

I don't see why clearcase expects this because a baseline applies on Stream...not a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`cleartool mkbl` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkbl.htm) (which is the command behind the "Make Baseline") mentions:

```
-vie/w view-tag
```

> Specifies the view from which to create baselines. Baselines are created in the stream that the view is attached to.
>
> For example, if you are working in `coyne_dev_view`, but want to create a baseline from the configuration specified by the view `coyne_integration_view`, use `-view coyne_integration_view`.
>   **This option creates a baseline in the project's integration stream that includes all the checked-in versions contained in `coyne_integration_view`**.
>   If you do not specify view-tag, the current view is used.

In other words, making a baseline is about putting a label on a version of each files of a given component for a given stream.
Questions:

- which Stream? Answer: the one referenced by a view
- which version? answer: the one selected by the config spec of the view (ie not necessarily the latest one created on a Stream)

So to know what to label, ClearCase needs a view when making a baseline.

Comment: very well explained. Thanks :)